# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'low working hours'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, naivebayes

While implementing Logistic Regression on some bank data I faced an error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'low working hours'. Here is the code I have tried until now.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

scaler = RobustScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-bbda4468bb89> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 scaler = RobustScaler()
      4 
----> 5 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
      6 
      7 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   2062 
   2063     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 2064         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   2065 
   2066     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'low working hours'
```

Comment: `'low working hours'` is a value of your dataset. You have to clean your data first

Comment: See the excellent [documentation on working with text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)